# How to recover Google Chrome tabs after Windows 10 reinstall?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I just recovered from a Windows 10 disk crash and I am going through the long process of recovery. Windows restore won't work on a different disk/product key.

I renamed the computer the same name, same user name and same domain. Was also able to copy AppData, Config and other critical directories including "Program Files" and "ProgramData" which were copied after the new Windows 10 install.  The old Chrome install was copied to the "Program Files (x86)" before reinstalling Chrome.

Chrome's extensions all seem to start up perfectly. The normal sync account login worked, so I have my bookmarks passwords, etc.  However, the tabs were not brought back when Chrome restarted.

How can I get my tabs back?

Answer (score 4):

Well that wasn't long...

When Chrome (re)installs, it overwrites **`CurrentSession`, `CurrentTabs`, `CustomDictionary.txt`** in **`%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`** directory.

Once installed, ensuring Chrome is not running in the background, copy the original files to **`%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`** directory.  Start Chrome and the tabs recover.